# Finding for what values of $y$ $f_{X|Y}(x|y)$ is defined

Tags: probability, probability-theory

[image]
Find the conditional density  function $f_{X|Y}(x|y)$.   Do  not  forget  to  indicate  where  the density is non-zero. For what values of $y$ is this conditional density defined?

First, I found that $f_Y(y) = \frac{14y}{3}(1-y^{\frac{3}{2}})$ for $0 \leq y \leq x^2$ and $f_Y(y)=0$ otherwise. Then, I found that

$f_{X|Y}(x|y) = 2x^{-4}y$. Now, I am unsure as to how to find for what values of $y$ this is defined. Would it simply be $0 \leq x \leq 1$ and $0 \leq y \leq x^2$, as given in the question?

Comment: The support for $f_Y(y)$ should not include $x$.

Comment: How can I find the support of $x$? I am not quite sure..

Comment: How did you find the supported function *without* knowing the domain of integration?

Comment: I just used a graphing calculator to find the region, and got it from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The support for $f_Y(y)$ must not include $x$ ; it is neither an argument nor a free variable.

Now the domain of $0\leq x\leq 1$ and $0\leq y\leq x^2$ is also $0\leq y\leq 1$ and $\surd y\leq x\leq 1$.

$$\begin{align}f_Y(y) &= \int_{\surd y}^1 14 x^2 y\,\mathbf 1_{0\leq y\leq 1}\,\mathrm d x\\ &=\tfrac {14}3 y(1-y^{3/2})\,\mathbf 1_{0\leq y\leq 1}\\[4ex] f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y) &= \dfrac{3 x^2}{(1-y^{3/2})}\,\mathbf 1_{0\leq y\leq 1}\mathbf 1_{\surd y\leq x\leq 1}\end{align}$$

---

$\mathbf 1_{a\leq z\leq b}$ is a indicator function; peicewise equalling $1$ when the index is satisfies, and $0$ otherwise:$$\mathbf 1_{a\leq z\leq b}=\begin{cases}1&:& a\leq z\leq b\\0&:&\textsf{otherwise}\end{cases}$$